# How do I integrate the Color module in my theme?

Tags: theming

I have installed drupal 8.4.2 and created a subtheme with base theme
   bootstrap. I want to customize settings adding the color module, but
   really I do not know what steps I am missing.

- I have enabled color module (it's in core)
- I have copied (from bartik) the color directory and files
- I have edited color.inc to have  my custom color schemes
- I  have edited THEME.theme adding this:

  ```
  function MYTHEME_process_html(&$variables) {
    // Hook into color.module.
    if (module_exists('color')) {
      _color_html_alter($variables);
    }
  }
  function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
      // Hook into color.module
      if (module_exists('color')) {
          _color_page_alter($variables);
      }
  }
  ```

As a result I have white page with no rendering. (It's not cache issue) and I guess my problem is with **.theme** file 
I'd like to know where to find the instructions (drupal.org has not much). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8vVfmQLmAA) about how to do this in Bootstrap.  There's also a [more general video for other themes by the same person.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl4sxQEvKOI)

You'll need to use a LESS or SASS subtheme; the most basic subtheme that just uses regular CSS will not work because the Color module will change the values of the variables.

You will also need a way to compile the LESS/SASS on the server that you use the Color module on, so if you plan to make adjustments on your production server, you will need something like the [LESS module](https://www.drupal.org/roject/less), which does not yet have an official release for Drupal 8 (might still work, needs testing).

You can also find a [feature request on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1636100) for putting this directly into Bootstrap, but it hasn't made any progress in the past couple years.