# How to style a custom theme setting form

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I have a set of custom theme settings defined in my theme.

They are fully integrated into my theme and appear on the theme's setting page but they are not styled. I use the seven admin theme.

I would like to style the forms on the admin pages; similarly to how other core modules like color, logo etc are styled.

How does one go about this?

Ideally, I would group my settings, place them in a div and give the entire group a title and help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I integrate the Color module in my theme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250870/how-do-i-integrate-the-color-module-in-my-theme)

Comment: Show a screenshot of the other theme settings styled as you described please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's just these two steps:

1. Define a library from `MYMODULE.libraries.yml`.
2. Attach the library to your form.

---

See [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module).

> #### Attaching a library to a form
>
> As forms are just render arrays, attaching a library works just the same:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Implements hook_form_alter().
>  */
> function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
>   /* @var Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface $entity */
>   $formObject = $form_state->getFormObject();
>   if ($formObject instanceof \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormInterface) {
>     $entity = $formObject->getEntity();
>     if (
>       $entity->getEntityTypeId() === 'node'
>       && in_array($entity->bundle(), ['organisation', 'location', 'event', 'article'])
>     ) {
>       $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'yourmodule/yourlibrary';
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

---

To add additional wrapper divs around some single or multiple form elements you can nest them into [containers](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Container.php/class/Container/8.2.x) or [fieldsets](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Fieldset.php/class/Fieldset/8.2.x). For example:

> #### class Container
>
> Provides a render element that wraps child elements in a container.
>
> Surrounds child elements with a  and adds attributes such as
>   classes or an HTML ID.
>
> Usage example:
>
> ```
> $form['needs_accommodation'] = array(
>   '#type' => 'checkbox',
>   '#title' => $this
>     ->t('Need Special Accommodations?'),
> );
> $form['accommodation'] = array(
>   '#type' => 'container',
>   '#attributes' => array(
>     'class' => 'accommodation',
>   ),
>   '#states' => array(
>     'invisible' => array(
>       'input[name="needs_accommodation"]' => array(
>         'checked' => FALSE,
>       ),
>     ),
>   ),
> );
> $form['accommodation']['diet'] = array(
>   '#type' => 'textfield',
>   '#title' => $this
>     ->t('Dietary Restrictions'),
> );
> ```

The D7 [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x) still is the most useful resource for that. Though you might want to check for changes on the D8 equivalent: [Form and render elements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.2.x).